# Should VCL Components Use Thread-Safe Functions

Tags: multithreading, delphi, thread-safety, custom-component

I am working on a custom VCL-only date edit component. Am planning on using the System.SysUtils.FormatDateTime function to convert a TDate to a string. There are two versions of FormatDateTime--one is thread-safe and the other is not. Since the VCL is not thread-safe, should I prefer the thread-safe version or is the non thread-safe version okay to use?

Comment: Visual components are not thread-safe, so it doesn't matter which you use. The component cannot be used from a thread.

Comment: The overload is not just about thread safety. It's more about customizing the format settings without affecting global settings. If your component needs to convert a date/time to a string in a specific format, use the overload, regardless of threading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr** use threadsafe version

If you use the non threadsafe version then you constrain any consumer of your component not to use that same non  threadsafe version in a thread.

That's not an unreasonable constraint by any measure. Using the non threadsafe version is only really viable in a program that never does so away from the main thread. So a program would have to be breaking the rules in the first place for your component to be caught up in the fallout.

Having said that, a component author should as a principle avoid making any assumptions about the consuming program. So best practice is to call the threadsafe version. Then there can be no debate. Your program cannot be involved in any thread safety issue with these locale global variables.

Comment: There can be a debate :) Why would one call a method of a visual control from a non main thread? I would accept a thread safe interface that is consumed by the control, not that one calls a method or use a property accessor of a visual control from within a worker thread. I would never design my visual control to be thread safe. It's just the consumer's responsability to not call any of its methods. P.S. you might also add that you should then (most probably) listen to locale settings change (if you want to reflect such changes in control's output).

Comment: @Victoria Any code in the application can call the RTL function. It need not be a method of the component.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your point here. That non thread safe `FormatDateTime` overload exists IMHO just for backwards compatibility. That access to that global format settings variable should have been designed as thread safe is another point. My point is that from a visual control you don't need to be afraid to use any of them. If you want to have a customizable format, use the thread safe overload (optionally listening to `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message to reflect user settings if you decide to).

Comment: Well, that any code in the application can call any RTL function is a good wish, but you just need to be careful in Delphi. But not here. Here it's just the developer's fault if they try to call a visual control's method from a worker thread.

Comment: @Victoria That's what I said. But there's no point getting caught up in the cross fire.

Comment: No, no, please. I didn't mean it anyhow bad :-) I just disagree with your opinion (you don't need to be afraid to call any of them because it's a visual control) and said almost the same _"So long the caller will be the main thread, it doesn't matter if you choose a non thread safe variant of the function."_ We can clean this discussion if you don't like it, just let me know ;-)

Comment: Let's assume I provide a custom string as the Format parameter in FormatDateTime, like FormatDateTime('dd-mmm-yyyy', Date()). Does that make any difference in the answer?

Comment: For that format, the result depends on the short month names which are part of the locale. So it's no different. It's really not hard to call the version that accepts format settings record.

Answer (score 1):

So long the caller will be the main thread, it doesn't matter if you choose a non thread safe variant of the function. Which in this case seems to be (if you are not creating inside of your component a worker thread from which you were calling that function, and you adhere to the rule that you won't use your control inside any worker thread, you'll be safe with it).

But there's more to consider. If you have recent Delphi version and keep [**UpdateFormatSettings**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.UpdateFormatSettings) property enabled, a globally declared format settings variable used in non thread safe overload of the [**FormatDateTime**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.FormatDateTime) function will get updated when the user modifies their local settings on their system. I can't say anything about a control notification (so you could update the output) because I'm having only D2009 by hand right now and these changes has been added later.